# I need to create replica of asp.net in classic asp code. Please suggest

Tags: asp-classic

I need classic asp code of following asp.net code.

asp.net-System.Environment.MachineName

asp.net-Server.MapPath

Answer (score 2):

ASP Server.MapPath doesn't support the resolution of "~/" at the start of URL as ASP.NET version does.  Here is code I posted here last year:

```
Function UrlContent(sUrl) 
    If InStr(1, sUrl, "~/") = 1 Then 
        UrlContent = ApplicationPath & Mid(sUrl, 2) 
    Else 
        UrlContent = sUrl 
    End If 
End Function 

Function ApplicationPath() 

    Dim pos: pos = Len(Request.ServerVariables("INSTANCE_META_PATH")) + 6 

    ApplicationPath = Mid(Request.ServerVariables("APPL_MD_PATH"), pos) 

End Function
```

The `UriContent` takes the passed in URL and resolves an "~/" to return a url relative to the host website.  So an MapPath equivalent to ASP.NETs code is:

```
Dim physicalPath : physicalPath = Server.MapPath(UrlContent(virtualPath))
```

Getting the machine name is much harder since you need some access to the windows API.  The server variable called "SERVER_NAME" is simply the host name used in the request so its not the same as the actually windows machine name.

Its moderately easy to create a .NET COM Interop dll that will allow script to access the Environment.